# Windows WebView custom scheme

Tags: windows, uwp

I've a WebView in a UWP that fires custom URIs via javascript. For e.g. "mraid://close" - I need to listen to such calls and take an action over it.

At the moment, I am getting callback only in

```
private void webView_OnUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentified(WebView sender, WebViewUnsupportedUriSchemeIdentifiedEventArgs args) {
            var url = args.Uri.ToString();
            args.Handled = true;
        }
```

What should I do to properly listen to it? (probably via notifyScript)

Answer (score 0):

When you prepare to click and call, you can add `window.external.notify()` in html file to notification your WebView. And your WebView need to subscribe the `ScriptNotify` event. In this case, when you call the method, the ScriptNotify event will be triggered and you can do something in it.

Comment: it is an external webview that i do not control - I have a javascript that this HTML calls. how can I solve it in js

Comment: What is the meaning of the "it is an external webview that i do not control"? Can you explain it in more detail? In addition, If convenient, can you provide a simple sample to let us understand better?

Comment: It is an advertiser's code that runs in the webview - I do not control it.

Comment: Why you want to listen to such calls? My suggestion is you can subscribe the NavigationStarting event, and use regular expressions to determine if uri is your scheme. When you call, the event will be triggered. Then you can do some of the operations you want.